# Alternative access to application files when server is down

Tags: google-drive-api, report, nas

I have an **application** that generates some **reports at every hour**. These reports are very **critical (and sensitive)** to the users and the **only access is through the application** (excel/pdf generation in memory with database) with previous **user/password/role validation**.

Last week the **server that host the application shut down for several hours** (hardware failure) and the **users could not retrieve** those reports (and i cant access to the db inmediatly).

**My client needs to at least access the last generated reports**. For example, if the failures occurs at 5 pm, he needs the report of the 4 pm.

So, **i thought in store the reports in other place**. The server/network administration is not my responsability. I dont have another server (and i cant avoid the network or hardware failures for ever), but i have a hard drive connected to the same server network (NAS).

Also i am thinking in storing the reports in Google Drive (client G suite with some encryption) or some other cloud service. But i am aware that i need permanent internet access.

¿What do you recommend me to do?

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach uses Nginx and creates multiple instances of the executable file and point to it if one instance stay down, the other instance will serve and the app will be live

Comment: I know. But those instances would run in the same server, so ¿what happens if the server/cluser/cloud fails?